# Dead display on acer notebook

Tags: windows, laptop

I have an Acer v5 notebook which needed a CMOS reset, so I opened it and removed the CMOS battery and reinstalled it after about 20 seconds.

When I connected everything and closed it up again, everything was working (CPU Fan, HDD spinning, dvd drive, etc). except the display was dead (not even back light). I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the LVDS (display) cable is securely seated on the main board - some are more easily dislodged than others, depending on the connector style.

Have you tried an external display to check that everything else is working as it should?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've ensured that all cables are properly secured. I've also connected the notebook to an external display in order to test, however still nothing ..

Comment: Should have thought of this before but have you tried cycling through the display output options with the external monitor connected, by pressing **Fn** and **F5/F6** (can't remember which one cycles the display but pretty sure it's one of those)?

Comment: Yes Tried that.This is something I haven't encountered before .. power LED is on and the rest of the devices but display is dead. After a few minutes (3-4 minutes) everything powers off again

Comment: Okay, couple more questions - what led you to clear the CMOS by removing the battery - and, does the system sound like it's actually booting (usual hard drive sounds etc.), or could it possibly be stuck at (or before) the POST tests without a display to indicate what's happening?

Comment: 1. Reason to reset CMOS - I switched to legacy bios mode from UEFI bios, and after restarting to affect that switch, the computer was stuck in a loop .. gets past POST and says 'no OS found' and restarts.

2. The HDD spins  like when you firstly boot up a computer, however no display, not even backlight; hence doesnt even get to the POST screen. 

Test - I tried taking off the RAM stick and booted again, however no beeps.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like the system is powering up but not POSTing or proceeding to the boot sequence. Various faults should produce beeps, CPU issues *can* cause symptoms like yours without producing a beep code but so can a corrupt BIOS. Now, I found this which describes the same symptoms as yours which may be helpful... http://community.acer.com/t5/2014-Archives/black-screen-flash-bios-V5-571/m-p/250086#M8219

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll give the instructions in that article a try and let you know of the outcome.